# How to send text to some bash command outside python?

Tags: python, bash, unix, pipe

### I have script which does some work:

```py
python the_script.py
```

After this script is finished, I want to `cd` into a directory the script makes and do bash stuff there.

### I want to achieve this:

```py
python the_script.py | cd
```

### I have tried

`sys.stdout.wrte("directory_name")`, but it doesn't work.

---

I can make a variable a then use it, but that's not the point of me asking the question, I want to know how to pipe stuff to other commands with python and do `python+bash` scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Try `cd "$(python the_script.py)"`.

- `$(...)` part will be the output of `the_script.py`.
- Then `"..."` will quote the output, to safely handle folder names that include whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

A construct such as `some_command | cd` by itself does not make any sense, because `cd` ignores stdin. Also, your approach suffers from the problem that it relies on the fact that the stdout of your Python program must then contain **only** the directory name and no other information. As soon as you write something else to stdout (`print "something"`) your program will break.

If it is a **necessity** that `the_script.py` decides on its own, which directory to create, write the directory name to some file instead of stdout, and process this file inside your bash script after your script finished. In this case I would let the caller define the filename via an environment variable:

```
export file_holding_name_for_new_directory=$PWD/foo.$$ 
python the_script.py
if [[ -f $file_holding_name_for_new_directory ]]
then
   cd $(<$file_holding_name_for_new_directory)
   rm $file_holding_name_for_new_directory
   # ... any further processing
else
  : # error in the_script.py
fi
```

Inside the_script.py, you create the directory, and if this succeeds, fetch the content of the environment variable, create a file of that name and write into this file the name of your directory.

Of course passing the name of this file via an environment variable is only one way to do it. Another possibility would be to pass this name on the command line:

```
file_holding_name_for_new_directory=$PWD/foo.$$ 
python the_script.py $file_holding_name_for_new_directory
if [[ -f $file_holding_name_for_new_directory ]]
then
   cd $(<$file_holding_name_for_new_directory)
   rm $file_holding_name_for_new_directory
   # ... any further processing
else
  : # error in the_script.py
fi
```

Which approach you take, is a matter of taste.

Comment: You are right about not being able to print anything else other than the directory name in the python script. Thanks to you I learnt that cd doesn't read stdin. And using environment variables is what I am doing but that approach won't be cross platform I think.  Thanks for the valuable info.

Comment: In what respect do you mean "not being not cross platform"? If you have a platform running bash, you have environment variables. For me, the different is mostly aesthetically: Passing information via the command line is genereally considered, while using the environment is easy to do, but smells like a "quick-and-dirty" solution and has some drawbacks when it comes to maintenance.

Comment: I admit I used too big of a word when I said "cross platform". I mean that anyone, whether windows or linux or unix, the_script should be useful.

Comment: As long as you stick with bash and Python, the only thing to worry would be cases such as running a Python built for native Windows with a bash from Cygwin (perhaps problems with pathes being passed from one side to the next). In any case, you would have to list the environments you want to run it, and what kind of implementation of bash and Python you are thinking of. In general, it might make sense that you even talk about the concrete version of bash / Python so that you are on the safe side (though for your problem, the version does not seem to matter).

Comment: Yeah, the_script is mostly standalone. But if one wants to integrate it into more stuff or want to automate stuff, they most probably are going to use bash. Like you said, I don't actually need to worry about "cross platform". Thanks for the input.
BTW. This is not production level or anything, just my personal project.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to automatically change location
to the new directory and [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run `bash` commands directly from the `python` script, something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

os.chdir('your directory')
sp.run(['ls', '-l'])
```

Comment: Alexound thanks for letting me know about running bash script in python. But I want to make it possible that who uses this script can use the info from the script without changing the source directly.